# What is the maximum resolution of a Visio M190VA monitor?

Tags: resolution, hdmi, dvi

Page 44 of the user manual says 1366x768, but it also says: Supports  640x480,  800x600,  1024x768,  1360x768  via  RGB  or  1920x1080i  via
HDMI®.  http://images10.newegg.com/User-Manual/User_Manual_89-262-071.pdf

Doesn't 1080 mean that it is capable of 1080 horizontal lines?

Follow up question: assuming that it IS capable of 1080 horizontal, how do I get there? Control Panel/Display says that the max is 1360x768, but we need more than that. The motherboard is an ASUS P8H67-M2/S1 which has a DVI output.  Is it just a matter of downloading a new driver and buying a DVI-HDMI cable, or is it time to upgrade the monitor?

thanks in advance,

Alan.

Comment: If the monitor supports 1920x1080 only through HDMI then it's time to upgrade your computer to one that has a HDMI out...

Comment: DVI and HDMI are electrically compatible, so you can get a DVI to HMDI converter cable for cheap if you want to try the HDMI input on the monitor.

Comment: The screen's native resolution is 1366x768.  That's the maximum actual detail it can display, regardless of the input.  The monitor has built-in scaling to accept 1920x1080 content and interpolate it to fit the screen (losing detail).  You can't view 1920x1080 content at full detail.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. So it emulates 1080 lines, but is still ultimately 768. I guess that means everything will appear about 40% smaller on screen. Techie007 - that's what I was thinking of trying.  I think I might have one lying around somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `1366x768` you see under *resolution* in the specification table is the *native resolution*, that is, the physical number of pixels: 1366 columns and 768 lines. All other resolutions are scaled or cropped when they are displayed.

The `i` after `1920x1080i` means *interlaced*, the monitor gets two alternating half-images with the even or odd 540 of the 1080 lines, and scales and blends them to 768 lines.

The best resolution for this monitor is the `1360x768` you already see in the control panel. Anything else will have worse quality.

Comment: You're right about the native resolution of the screen, it's 1366x768.  The monitor will accept certain higher resolutions from the computer and interpolate them to fit the screen.  However, your explanation of 1080i is incorrect.  1080i is 1920x1080 pixels, with only the odd or even rows displayed with each frame.  There is actually 1920x1080 pixels of information composing the image, but it takes two frames to see it all.  The interpolation of that to 1360x768 is an unrelated process.

Comment: @fixer1234: Yes, that's exactly what I wrote. Edited to make it (hopefully) clearer.

Comment: It blends them to 1080 lines, not 768 lines.  Then it takes that and interpolates the result to fit the screen as a separate process.  My issue is that the description sounds like 1080i is really only 768 lines, which would also imply that you could view 1080i content at full resolution on a 768 line monitor.

Comment: @fixer1234 That would be a waste of memory. It's much more efficient to just keep the last 540 lines, and then correctly blend them with the new 540 lines. At least that's how the deinterlacing scaler on old NVidia architectures work (which I happen to know). And yes, the effective resolution of the blended 1080 lines is just 768 lines (though the effective resolution of 1080i in general is 1080 lines). Which is why it doesn't make sense to use this mode, and why I described it that way. So we mean the same thing, you just want to phrase it differently.

Comment: @fixer1234: The alternative without using memory in the monitor is to upscale the even/odd 540 lines in two different ways to 768 lines. This is even worse.